# CSS Transitions in Classes with Pseudo Hover

Tags: css

Okay, so I can't figure out why this isn't working.
The hover effect with the fade in doesn't seem to be applying to this.

**css**

```
.panel_button {

}


.panel_button a {
webkit-transition: all 10.0s ease; 
-moz-transition: all 10.0s ease; 
transition: all 10.0s ease;
background-color: #000;
display: block;
width: 50%;
height: 160px;
color: #000099;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.panel_button a:hover {
background: #808080;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**Header page**

```
  <div class="panel_button" style="display: visible;"> <a href="#">BLOG</a> </div>
```

The website where this code is implemented is at niu-niu.org

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your `webkit-transition: all 10.0s ease;` is missing the dash at the beginning. Change it to this:

```
-webkit-transition: all 10.0s ease;
```